# Add certificates the same way the Certificate Import Wizard does [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, vpn

I have configured a powershell script, which creates a vpn conection profile.
To make it work i need to add proper certificate.

Everything works fine when i add a certificate manually to local machine:

[image]

More detailed regarding importing certificate manualy:
[Info](https://www.pcwrt.com/2019/10/how-to-set-up-ikev2-vpn-connection-on-windows-10-with-certificate-or-eap-mschap-v2-authentication/)

I'm trying to perform this task via powershell, but it doesn't work (script seems to work, but i am not sure to which stores should i copy certificate). In contrary to manual method - the certificate added by my powershell script is invisible for vpn connection.

```
#add certificate
$cert_name=$env:USERNAME+"@vpn.contoso.com.p12"
$cert_loc="\\ad\deploy\other\certs\"+$cert_name
$secure_pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "contoso987%#" -AsPlainText -Force
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $cert_loc -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $secure_pwd
# Add vpn connection
Add-VpnConnection -Name "Example VPNX" -ServerAddress "vpn.example.com" -AuthenticationMethod "MachineCertificate" -TunnelType "IKEv2" -EncryptionLevel "Maximum" -SplitTunneling $True
```

I would like to do it the same way the certificate import wizard does. Does anyone have experience in that ?

PS
I've changed addresses in codes etc.

Kind Regards,
Tamara

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to post the solution. Although it is not developed in powershell it solves the problem completely. It is possible to import these kind of certificates from command prompt:

```
certutil -f -p Some_password -importpfx "\\ad\somepath\certificate.p12"
```